# How to get the row count of each table of a Schema in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

I have a schema in hive which is having 100 + tables. Am trying to get the list of tables and the row count of each table

I tried below:

First i got the list of tables by:  `Show tables in <SCHEMA NAME>`

After that i tried count queries for every table like

```
Select Count(*) from Schema.table1 UNION
Select Count(*) from Schema.table2 UNION
Select Count(*) from Schema.table3 UNION ...etc.
```

Looking for any simpler method/query to get the list of tables and its count together in
HIVE. I am connected to Hive through Dbeaver

Comment: Do not spam tags. How is this question related to MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: If you gather table statistics then you may issue `describe formatted <table_name>` and get the number of rows in `numRows` parameter's value